# Error processing method: shareFileAsync during release buid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having this problem in the compilation on Android.

When I use the method:

```
await Share.RequestAsync (new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = "Shared File:" + nameFile,
    File = new ShareFile (fullPathFile)
});
```

I get this error

```
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void WorkFlow2.Services.Utility/<shareFileAsync>d__8::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'WorkFlow2.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Essentials.ShareRequestBase::set_Title(System.String)
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
--- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
in MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
in Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
in Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
in MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()  WorkFlow2.Android
```

This error returns at compile time for the release.
During the "debug" phase it works correctly.

Comment: have you followed the Android specific setup instructions in the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Candroid

Comment: I solved the problem ... in practice I was missing xamarin.essential thing to the strange because I started doing this application for over a month and it had always been there.

Anyway thanks to your comment I have reviewed the configuration that I took for granted since it had been carried out previously.